# Exetute the GUI in one Pc and the Process in Other

Tags: c++, qt

I'm currently developing a GUI in C++ over Qt's Framework for a really heavy program.

So my question is: Can I run my interface in one Pc and the heavy problems in other one? It's a Ubuntu's program.

Comment: Whar do you mean by  "heavy problems" exactly, could you provide some code examples? It's possible to do so but maybe you should try using multithreading first

Comment: A usual and soft process use 8 cores and more than 20gb of RAM.

Comment: Qt remote objects might be an option: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtremoteobjects-index.html or any other means of communication (REST, plain client-server using sockets, etc.)